# using a PHP function multiple times but only display something inside the function once

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that selects and returns data from a database, i want to run this function multiple times and display a table heading only once,

for example

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Heading 1</td>
    <td>Heading 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php MyFunctionName($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4); ?>
```

but i want the table heading to be inside the function, is this possible?

Comment: Simplest way: Give it an additional parameter that tells it whether or not to output a table heading.

Comment: Do you mean you want the function to output the table heading? If yes- Just add a parameter for the header.  - EDIT: CBroe beat me to it.

Comment: It is, but you shouldn't do it. Each piece of code should have a single responsibility. If you want to call a function that prints headers and then data, make it *another* function.

Comment: To add to what @Jon said, you need to be very careful about mixing display logic and data handling logic.  Ideally your goal should be to abstract the two things away from each other, and not have a function that both queries a database, but then also formats and outputs an HTML table.  Separate those responsibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a static variable:

```
function MyFunctionName($args...) {
    static $is_first_run = true;
    if( $is_first_run) {
        // do stuff
        $is_first_run = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Is also a horrible way to write code. :/

Comment: @Jon Agreed - functions should ideally produce same output for a given input (except in particular cases like `rand()` - and even that's not getting the same input each time, unless you set the seed to the same... bah, forget this) But sometimes this can be useful, for instance to only run a MySQL query once and save its results in a static variable so the function can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional, optional boolean parameter to the function, which determines if it should print the heading or not. At the first call, you give true as the last parameter, otherwise you simply omit it.

```
function MyFunctionName(var1,var2,var3,var4,showHeading = false) {
    if(showHeading) {
        // show the heading
    }
    // do the other code
}
```

First call:
`MyFunctionName(var1,var2,var3,var4,true);`

Other calls:
`MyFunctionName(var1,var2,var3,var4);`

**EDIT:** Sorry, too late.

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting your function.

```
<?    
function MyFunctionName(){
 $Q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$results ='';
$header = '';
$headerBuilt = false;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $results .= '<tr>';
    foreach($r AS $i => $v){
        if(!$headerBuilt){
            $header .= '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        }
        $results .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    }
    $results .= '</tr>';
    $headerBuilt = true;
}
$table = '<table><tr>'.$header.'</tr>'.$results.'</table>';
return($table);
}  
?>
```

not tested